# Plugin for Indentation in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, indentation, auto-indent

I have my complete code in this format in sublime text. I wish to indent it properly without manual intervention. In Sublime Text 3 we have only Reindent option but that cannot change the following to the one following that.

```
<div> Dhrub</div>
```

Formating I needed for my html/css/javascript file

```
<div>
Dhrub
</div>
```

Following is a overview of my full docs

SERVICES

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="F col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6"> <h2>We provide home services in 35 countries competing with brands of Amazon  </h2> </div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
    <div class="row urbanclap_content">
      <div class="urbanclap_subcontent col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 "> <div class="glyphicon-ring"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope glyphicon-bordered" ></div> <h4> Home Services Express</h4> <p>We provide home services in 35 countries competing with brands of Amazon</p></span></div>
      <div class="urbanclap_subcontent col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 "><div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope glyphicon-bordered"></div><h4> Home Services Express</h4> <p>We provide home services in 35 countries competing with brands of Amazon</p></span></div>
      <div class="urbanclap_subcontent col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 "> <div class="glyphicon-ring"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope glyphicon-bordered"></div><h4> Home Services Express</h4> <p>We provide home services in 35 countries competing with brands of Amazon</p></span></div>
      <div class="urbanclap_subcontent col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 "><div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope glyphicon-bordered"> </div><h4> Home Services Express</h4> <p>We provide home services in 35 countries competing with brands of Amazon</p></span></div>

    </div>
```

I have searched plugin but not found the one which does that.
Hope I will find an alternate here.

Comment: Next time, use Google to search for your question, and relevant answers on SO will appear at the top. Also, while you are composing your question, a list entitled **Questions that may already have your answer** shows up with potentially relevant questions. **Use that list** and open up the suggested questions in new tabs. This site has been around for over 7 years, if you suspect a question has already been asked, it probably has. Duplicates like this just waste time and effort.